# Let $A,B\subset \Bbb R.$ Then prove that $\overline{A\cap B}\subset \overline{A}, \overline{B}.$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A,B\subset \Bbb R.$ Then prove that $\overline{A\cap B}\subset \overline{A}\subset \overline{B}.$ Give example to show, $\overline{A\cap B}\neq \overline{A}\subset \overline{B}.$

I think, $\overline A$ denotes the closure of the set $A.$ Assuming this, notation, being used here, I feel the question invites some absurdity in here. For it suggests, to prove, $\overline{A}\subset \overline{B},$ where $A,B$ are just two arbitrary subset of $\Bbb R.$ It might not be true, that for any two sets, $\overline{A}\subset \overline{B}.$

However, I feel the part, where it says, $\overline{A\cap B}\subset \overline{A},$ is justified. Also, I have been able to show, that precisely, $\overline{A\cap B}\subset \overline{A},\overline{B},$ holds true.

Further, while solving this problem, I made a particular assumption that $A\subset B.$ This assumption makes us able to conclude $\overline A\subset \overline B.$ I did this as:

Let $x\in \overline{A\cap B}=(A\cap B)\cup (A\cap B)',$ (where $(A\cap B)'$ represents the set of limit points of $A\cap B$). This implies, $x\in A\cap B$ or $x\in (A\cap B)'$.

Let us first assume the former case, i.e  $x\in A\cap B.$ This, means, $x\in A\subset \overline{A}(=A\cup A')$ and similarly, $x\in B\subset \overline {B}(=B\cup B')$ where, $A',B'$ are the set of limit points of $A,B$ respectively. So, we have, $x\in \overline A,\overline{B}.$ Hence, $\overline{A\cap B}\subset \overline{A}$ and $\overline{A\cap B}\subset \overline{B}.$

Now, let us assume, that $x\in (A\cap B)'$. This means , $x$ is a limit point of the set $A\cap B$ which further implies that there exists a convergent sequence say, $(a_n)\in A\cap B$ which converges to $x.$ This means, $(a_n)\in A$ and so, $x\in A'\subset \overline A$. Similarly, $(a_n)\in B\implies x\in B'\subset \overline B.$ (Here, $A',B'$ are the set of limit points of $A,B$ respectively.) Thus, we have, $\overline{A\cap B}\subset \overline{A}$ and $\overline{A\cap B}\subset \overline{A}.$

*We assume, $A\subset B.$* This implies that if there exists a convergent sequence, say $(p_n)$ in $A$ with $\lim ]_n=p$ then, $(p_n)\in B$ as well. Now, $p\in A'$ and as $\lim p_n=p$ then, $p\in B'$ so, $A'\subset B'.$

Again, we note that $\overline A=A\cup A'$ and $\overline B=B\cup B'$. As, $A\subset B$ and $A'\subset B'$ we may conclude, $\overline A\subset \overline B.$

Previously, we also proved, that $\overline {A\cap B}\subset \overline A.$ Using the fact, that $\overline A\subset \overline B$, we can say, that $\overline{A\cap B}\subset \overline A\subset \overline B,$ which is precisely what we're required to show.

Here, is a counter-example, stating that $\overline{A\cap B}\neq \overline A,\overline B.$ If, $A=\{\frac 1n+\frac 1m:m,n\in\Bbb N\},$ then, $A'=\{\frac 1n:n\in\Bbb N\}\cup \{0\}.$ If, $B=\{\frac 1k:k\in \Bbb N\}$ then, $B'=\{0\}.$ Now, $A\cap B=\phi$ and so, $(A\cap B)'=\phi.$ This means, $\overline {A\cap B}=\phi.$ But, $$\overline A=\{x,y:x\in A,y\in A'\},\overline B=\{p:p\in B\}\cup \{0\},$$ and $\overline{A\cap B}\neq \overline A,\overline B.$

---

This is how, I approached the problem. But the point is, I am unable to find a proper justification, why $\overline A\subset \overline B$ (if at all it's true) and hence, I ommitted it from my solution. Am I correct with my arguments and reasonings ?

The example I showed is faulty because, in that example, $A\cap B\neq \phi.$ Any help regarding finding a proper example will be much appreciated.

Comment: If there is no conditions on $A, B$, then it is not true. Consider $B=\emptyset, \overline{A}\ne\emptyset$.

Comment: @zkutch You mean, $\overline A\subset \overline B$ ?

Comment: Yes. It is not true for any $A,B$.

Comment: Either there is a typo in your book or you did not copy it correctly. It should be $\overline{A\cap B}\subset \overline{A}\cap \overline{B}$

Comment: Is it a typo? $\overline{A\cap B}\subset \overline{A}\cap \overline{B}$?

Comment: @MartinR I take it the former case. I rechecked, and I copied it correctly. I have further edited my post.

Comment: @Tim Seems to be so.

Comment: About how to do this corrected exercise: You may take the definition of closure as "the smallest closed subset containing $A$" and the argument would be simpler

Comment: @RichardChen Is the example I cited true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a space $X$ and a point $a \in X$, consider the particular point topology $\tau_a$ where the open sets are the ones that contain $a$ and the empty set. In this topology, given $x \neq a$ $A = \{a\}, B = \{x\}$
$$\overline{\{ a\}} = X$$
$$\overline{\{ x \}} = \{x\}$$
$$\overline{A \cap B} = \emptyset$$
$$\overline{\{ A \}}  \cap \overline{\{ B \}}= \{x\}$$